# A body is thrown into the air with an initial velocity of $v_0$ ft/sec. What initial velocity is required to double the maximum height?

Tags: derivatives, classical-mechanics

I'll post the question here and then show my workings out.

A body is thrown into the air with an initial velocity of $v_0$ ft/sec. What initial velocity is required to double the maximum height previously attained?

First I write the equation for velocity in feet.

$v=-32t+v_0$

Integrate to get s.

$s=-16t^2 + v_0t$

Calculate the maximum.

when $v=0$, $\frac{v_0}{32}=t$

Twice the distance is $2s=-32t^2+2v_0 t$

Substituting $\frac{v_0}{32}=t$ into this equation gives $2s=\frac{-v_0^2}{32}+\frac{v_0}{4}$

I then differentiate $2s$, now as $s_2$ to get the velocity required in terms of initial velocity.

$v_2=\frac{4-v_0}{16}$
$v_2=\frac{2-\sqrt(v_0)}{4}$

This is not the correct answer, suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're missing a constant of integration at the first $s$ step, although I'm not sure if that matters

Comment: Is this formula not known?$$v^2-{v_0}^2=2a\Delta x$$

Comment: "... Substituting $\frac{v_0}{32}=t$ into this equation gives..." Of course the new $t$ is different than the old $t$. Nobody can guarantee that the body will achieve the maximum height in the same time in both cases.

Comment: I am not familiar with $v^2−v_0^2=2a\delta x$

Comment: Thank you Stinking Bishop, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that

$${v_f}^2-{v_i}^2=2a\Delta x$$

where $v_i$ and $v_f$ denote initial and final velocities, respectively; $a$ is acceleration; and $\Delta x$ is the net displacement.

At its maximum height, the object has $0$ vertical velocity, so if it is thrown with initial velocity $v_0$ and is in freefall, then

$$0^2-{v_0}^2=-2g\Delta x\implies \Delta x=\dfrac{{v_0}^2}{2g}$$

where $g$ is the magnitude of the acceleration due to gravity.

If one wants the object to reach a maximum height twice as high, that would require scaling up $v_0$ by a factor of $\sqrt2$, since

$$\dfrac{(\sqrt2\,v_0)^2}{2g}=\dfrac{{v_0}^2}g=2\Delta x$$